# Java HashMap ways of adding a new entry if not already there

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this
HashMap<Integer, Set> map;

and for a given integer X, I wanna check if we already have an entry with the key as X, and if not create a new entry. what's the difference between the two practices here:

1.

```
    map.putIfAbsent(X, new HashMap<>());
```

2. 

```
    if (!map.containsKey(X)) {
        map.put(X, new HashSet<>());
    }
```

I originally thought they are 100% same, but in some edge cases where this thing is used in a recursion method, putIfAbsent causes stackOverFlow, but the second one works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. At one, you're storing a map against your key X and in the second, you're storing a hashset. Also, your stackoverflow exception occurs due to your recursion (and absence of a specific/any base case which ends the recursion), not due to your hashmap methods.

Comment: Please post code that can be compiled. Best [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

There are no such differences. Look at the HashMap class source code below:

```
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
    }
    ...
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        return putVal(hash(key), key, value, true, true);
    }
```

As you can see, there's no difference, apart from the 4th parameter in the `putVal(...)` method, which is a param called onlyIfAbsent.

Your stackoverflow exception occurs due to your recursion (and absence of a specific/any base case which should end the recursion), not due to your hashmap methods.

Answer (score 1):

The two code blocks cause a slightly different result (even with your typo of `HashMap` instead of `HashSet` - corrected in this answer).

This:

```
map.put(X, new HashSet<>());
```

creates a hash set with the default size, whereas this:

```
map.putIfAbsent(X, new HashSet<>());
```

doesn't compile, but if it were coded correctly as

```
map.putIfAbsent(X, HashSet::new);
```

creates a hash set whose size is `X`, because the constructor matches the signature of `new HashSet(size)`, and so this code style *only* works when the key type is `Integer` - not a good style to follow.

Comment: Can you explain clearly 1). how you can put a hashset against a key and also put a hashmap against same/another key in the same map? 2). Why the last statement creates a map of specific size? 3). Clarify the 3rd code segment. References to docs will also be helpful :)

Comment: @sbsatter 1) I just copy-pasted OP's code. I didn't even notice the typo - answer adjusted accordingly. 2) the 2nd param of putIfAbsent is a `Function<K, V>`, in this case `Function<Integer, Set>`. Coding `HashSet::new` will therefore invoke the constructor as `X -> new HashSet(X)`, which specified the initial size.